# How do I get a file with all the runtime dependencies of my gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle

I used a task `gradlew dependencies > file.txt` and I get a txt file with all my java project dependencies. But I only want to see runtime dependencies. Is there a configuration option for this.. I was not able to find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use option `--configuration confName` to filter dependencies for a specific configuration:

```
./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath > file.txt
```

See documentation : [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#example_rendering_the_dependency_report_for_a_custom_configuration)